# How to solve /dev/xvda1 100% usage issue?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk-usage, resize, disk-management

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04
/ ext4 filesystem**

As I did a "df -h", it shows that my "/dev/xvda1" is 100% full. I cannot even do a "tab" to list all folders/files under current directory. ( I got a "-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device" error).

Is there any safe way to expand the Filesystem without losing any data or do harm to OS?

Is it possible that I could get the "/dev/xvdb1" mounted on the top directory "/" so that I will have ample spaces to install libraries, etc. I do not think there is anything I could delete in the /usr/ directory. Or could I re-direct the "/" to another filesystem (e.g. /dev/xvdb1) ?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           985M   95M  890M  10% /run
/dev/xvda1      8.5G  7.8G  246M  100% /
tmpfs           4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb1      196G  9.4G  177G   6% /datadrive
tmpfs           985M     0  985M   0% /run/user/1003
```

This is the information when I logged in:

```
System information as of Tue Oct 20 11:48:32 PDT 2020

  System load:                    0.44
  Usage of /:                     91.8% of 8.49GB
  Memory usage:                   13%
  Swap usage:                     0%
  Processes:                      145
```

These are the directories taking up the most space:

```
$ sudo du -xch -d 3 / | awk '$1~/G/'
1.7G /usr/lib 
4.1G /usr 
1.2G /var/lib 
1.4G /var 
1.1G /lib 
7.8G / 
7.8G total
```

Comment: DO NOT delete things from `/usr` (unless it's in `/usr/local`). That's APT's job and you will likely break your system if you do that. What's the GB in `/var/lib`? I'd try and clean a minimal amount of space and shutdown before properly joining xvda and xvdb in an array which looks like the simplest solution. If you don't plan on installing any additional software, you could also migrate `var` to xvdb instead.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Thanks for the reply. Sorry I don't have many experiences as a superuser. What do you mean "properly joining xvda and xvdb in an array"? How do I do it?